Is the last step in the video necessary to prove exercise 1.4.1 in Durrett 1.4?
In Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples exercise 1.4.1,i.e., show that if $f\geq 0$ and $\int f d\mu=0$ then $f=0$ a.e.
It's easy to show that for any $\epsilon>0$, $\mu(\{x:f(x)>\epsilon\})=0$, I thought this is equivalent to $\mu(\{x:f(x)>0\})=0$ because $\epsilon$ could be arbitrarily small. However, I noticed the following excellent video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yeUaOopzgw  that provides a solution that does not stop here. His proof did not end with $\mu(\{x:f(x)>\epsilon\})=0$. Instead, he added an additional step that goes as $$\mu(\{x:f(x)>0\})=\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x:f(x)>\frac{1}{n}\}\right)=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\mu\left(\left\{x:f(x)>\frac{1}{n}\right\}\right)=0$$ Two questions: First, what's the theorem or lemma reference that justifies the second-to-last equality? Is it by the continuity from below property of the measure?   Second, is this last step really necessary in proving our desired result?

Yes, it is the continuity of the measure from below and yes, this step is necessary.

@geetha290krm Thanks! This is very helpful. I'm still a bit confused about the second question.  Because to show $a\leq b$, a common argument is to show $a\leq \epsilon +b$ for any $\epsilon>0$ (for example, in the proof of theorem 1.1.4 of this book). How does this problem differ from that situation?
